# Python execution differs if executed by systemd

Tags: python, subprocess, systemd

I have a simplest python file `notify.py`

```
import subprocess
import getpass


username = getpass.getuser()
print(username)

p = subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', 'test notification'], 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
p.communicate()
```

If I run this code in terminal: `python3 notify.py`
This code calls `notify-send` in subprocess to show a notification in KDE and it works as expected,
I get a small notification in bottom right corner.

I also wrote and installed a systemd `notify.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Notification

[Service]
User=me
Group=users
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/python3 /home/me/notify.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the problem is, if I try to run `# systemctl start notify.service` I don't get a notification. I know that notify-send can not show notifications if it called by root. So I change user and Group in .service file to my user and my group. I also write my current user name to STDOUT to check the user name. After I call it via systemd, I can see my user name printed in `journalctl`. What is a problem with my code? Please help!!!

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with Python? If instead of running `python3 notify.py` from the terminal, you run `notify-send "test notification"`, does it still work? If you replace `ExecStart=/bin/python3 /home/me/notify.py` with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/notify-send "test notification"`, does it still fail? If the answer to both of those is "yes", then it doesn't have anything to do with Python.

Comment: Yes you are right. Even if I call ExecStart=/usr/bin/notify-send "test notification" it fails. So it is not Python. but what could it be?

Comment: could you try ExecStart=bash -c "python3 /home/me/notify.py" to see if some environment variable is not set etc.?